# How to check whether a feature has been split in GeoTools?

Tags: geometry, features, area

In my program I am looking for a best place for a golf course. Three of the conditions are:

1. The course must be on a hill,
2. it must be at least 100 meters away from roads and
3. must not be larger than ***x***.

Some of the generated courses are divided into two pieces by a road in the middle.

My question is:

How do I get those pieces as separate features or geometries to check their area? Is that even possible? Can I  check if a certain geometry is whole, not split?

Edit: I am using geotools platform. (Feeling stupid that I forgot to mention)

Comment: which program are you using? have you tried multiparts to singleparts?

Comment: Any sensible answer would be software dependent; platforms like ArcGIS and GDAL/OGR both have methods to check if a geometry contains more than one part but first you would need to dissolve by Lot/plan to create your multipart polygons if that has not been done already - again, how you do this is software dependent. Please indicate what software/API you have available.

Comment: Forgot to mention. I am using geotools so I am looking for a java geotools solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I have found out how to do what I originally wanted to do.

So in geotools you can get the amount of split (separated) geometries in a feature using method `geometry.getNumGeometries();`

You can get the single geometry itself using

```
geometry.getGeometryN(i);
```

So to do whatever you need (i.e. create new features for each geometry) just use a for loop like this:

```
Geometry geometry = feature.getDefaultGeometry();
for (int i=0, n=geometry.getNumGeometries(); i<n; i++) {
   Geometry singleGeom = geometry.getGeometryN(i);
   /*Do whatever you need*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most GIS programs have Multiparts to single parts tools that will separate those features into individual parts.

Comment: This would make mulitpart detection *harder*, and isn't necessary to solve the task.